# Navigation to source of compiled lisp function?

Tags: help

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4222183/emacs-how-to-jump-to-function-definition-in-el-file and talk about navigation to source of functions.  They offer two options:

- M-x find-function
- C-h f  then use link in help buffer.

However, for a compiled function, neither work.

```
M-x find-function compilation-find-file
```

throws an error:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "Can’t find library /usr/share/emacs/26.1+gg1+7/lisp/progmodes/compile.el")
```

If I used the help function path, I see:

```
compilation-find-file is a compiled Lisp function.
```

How can I fix these?

Comment: This sounds like something specific to your installation/setup; `M-x find-function RET compilation-find-file RET` works fine for me (so long as `compile.el` has been loaded beforehand), despite `compilation-find-file` being a "compiled Lisp function". Does it work if you start with `emacs -Q` followed by `(require 'compile)` and then the `find-function` call?

Comment: Note that there is also `M-.` (`xref-find-definitions` since Emacs 25) for jumping to the definition of the identifier at point, as briefly mentioned in the linked SO post.

Comment: (require 'compile) does not change the observed behaviour.  I am wondering if I need to play with `source-directory' and/or `load-path'.

Comment: Why not just take a peak inside the directory where Emacs is looking to see what is there?  `/usr/share/emacs/26.1+gg1+7/lisp/progmodes` and also the parent directory.  If there is nothing there, then `grep` or manually look around for the `.el` and/or `.gz` files.  There are minimal installations that do not install the Lisp libraries, but that is not very common and is certainly not the default installation method.

Comment: @Realraptor `(require 'compile)` is needed because `compilation-find-file` is not autoloaded or otherwise defined at startup. I wasn't suggesting it as a solution to your issue. Have you tried reproducing your issue starting with `emacs -Q`? If it still doesn't work, then the problem lies with your installation, as lawlist mentions.

Comment: In particular, a Debian/Ubuntu/etc installation may not include everything you want, and you may be missing (and hence need to `apt-get install`) the `emacs-el` and `emacs25-common-non-dfsg` packages (substituting the version number as appropriate in the latter package name).  The former provides the elisp source files, and the latter provides the manuals.  You don't want to be lacking either of those things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that adding the -el for the emacs version I am using resolves the problem (as suggested by phils).

Comment: Note that you can accept your own answer.

Comment: On debain machines to install sources use the command "sudo apt install emacs-el"